# How do I allow remote connection in SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server

I've just installed SQL Server 2008 Express. But when I try to connect to database engine via SQL Server Management Studio I get "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" error. I want to allow remote connections to the server but Surface area configuration is missing in 2008. If I cannot connect to the server instance then how am I supposed to configure this feature? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** (SSCM) and under Service Protocols enable **TCP/IP** for your SQL Server Express instance (most likely called *SQLEXPRESS*).

Comment: ...and restart the instance.